# How to Join two tables data into UITableView using Sqlite iPhone and how to set NSDictionary object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsdictionary

How to join my two tables data into another screen in this Am Struck with the  NSDictionary,NSArray and NSString how to add object into NSDictionary?
Below is my DBClass.m

```
    #import "DBClass.h"

@implementation DBClass

+(NSString *)connectdb
{
    NSArray *docDir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dbFolder=[docDir objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:dbFolder])
    {
        [manager createDirectoryAtPath:dbFolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    NSString *dbPath=[dbFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"JoinsDB.sqlite"];
    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath])
    {
        [manager copyItemAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"JoinsDB.sqlite"] toPath:dbPath  error:nil];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);
    return dbPath;
}

+(BOOL)createTable
{
    NSString *dbpath=[DBClass connectdb];
    sqlite3 *dbObj;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
        const char *sql="create table Company(ID INTEGER,Name VARCHAR,Age INTEGER,Address VARCHAR,Salary INTEGER)";
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"tabel created successfull");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"tabel already created");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(dbObj);
    }
    return YES;
}

+(int)saveData:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
    sqlite3 *dbObj;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
    NSString *dbPath=[DBClass connectdb];
    const char *sql=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Company(ID,Name,Age,Address,Salary) values(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",[data objectAtIndex:0],[data objectAtIndex:1],[data objectAtIndex:2],[data objectAtIndex:3],[data objectAtIndex:4]]UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[data objectAtIndex:0]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[data objectAtIndex:1]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [[data objectAtIndex:2]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [[data objectAtIndex:3]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [[data objectAtIndex:4]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt executed properly");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt not executed");

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(dbObj);

    }
    return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(dbObj);
}


+(BOOL)createTable2
{
    NSString *dbpath=[DBClass connectdb];
    sqlite3 *dbObj;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
        const char *sql="create table Department(ID INTEGER,Dept VARCHAR,Emp_ID INTEGER)";
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"tabel created successfull");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"tabel already created");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(dbObj);
    }
    return YES;
}

+(int)saveData2:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
    sqlite3 *dbObj;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
    NSString *dbPath=[DBClass connectdb];
    const char *sql=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Department(ID,Dept,Emp_ID) values(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",[data objectAtIndex:0],[data objectAtIndex:1],[data objectAtIndex:2]]UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[data objectAtIndex:0]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[data objectAtIndex:1]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [[data objectAtIndex:2]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


        sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt executed properly");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt not executed");

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(dbObj);

    }
    return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(dbObj);
}

+(NSMutableArray *)getData
{
    sqlite3 *dbobj;
    NSString *dbpath  =[DBClass connectdb];
    NSMutableArray *readArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbobj)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;

        //**** NSString *string=@"SELECT name FROM emptable";
        NSString *string=@"SELECT EMP_ID, Age, DEPT FROM COMPANY INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON COMPANY.ID = DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID";

        const char *query=[string UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbobj, query, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
            NSMutableDictionary *readDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] forKey:@"Emp_ID"];

        [readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"Name"];
        [readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"Dept"];

                [readArray addObject:readDic];
                NSLog(@"%@",readDic);
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",readArray);
    sqlite3_close(dbobj);
    return readArray;   
}

@end
```

How to show in UITableview,and in Viewdidload what should can I do
This my JoinViewController.m

```
 #import "JoinViewController.h"
#import "DBClass.h"

@interface JoinViewController ()

@end

@implementation JoinViewController
@synthesize data,array;
@synthesize Table;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    array=[DBClass getData];
    for( NSDictionary *obj in array)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);

        [data addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"Emp_ID"]];
        [data addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"Name"]];
        [data addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"Dept"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"\n%d",[data count]);
    [Table reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
   // Return the number of sections.
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return 1;
   return [data count];


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Emp_ID"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Dept"];

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: In getdata method How to add two tables objects into the NSDictionary? And In Viewdidload and tableview.

Answer (score 0):

In your getdata method, your sql is asking for EMP_ID, Age, DEPT, but you're storing the data as Emp_ID, Name, Dept.  One says age, the other says name.  Also, you're duplicating the column numbers, getting a value from column 2, which would be DEPT, and you're storing it in Emp_ID, and you're getting the value from column 1 twice, which would be age, and storing it in Name and Dept.  Column 0 should be Emp_ID, 1 is Age (which you probably want to change to Name), 2 is DEPT.

You can also simplify your SQL statement a bit with:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, Age, DEPT FROM COMPANY, DEPARTMENT where COMPANY.ID = DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID;
```

Comment: Am edited 'Name' instead of 'Age'.I want to using join query the data will be shown, nothing will be happened.How to add object into NSDictionary in this I did wrong,how to add objects into two tables data

Comment: To add objects into two tables, have two UPDATE (or INSERT) sql statements, and wrap them in a transaction. The SQL statement I gave you will do a join. Your code to add objects to NSMutableDictionary looks OK. Probably you're not getting the data with the right sql to begin with.

Comment: In Jointviewcontroller viewdidload and cellforrowindexpath is correct or not?Adding objects.How it will be come to tableview.

Comment: The method you provide cellForRowAtIndexPath is called by the system whenever it wants some data from you.  Since you're storing the data in a NSMutableDictionary in memory, it makes sense to supply the data from there, as you're doing.